# The ` fetch("/createpost", {...} ` is not working properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb

The problem with the output is that when we click on the submit post button  , the backend sends the error
of please add all the fields . But if we click the button multiple times without doing any changes in the input or anything , the post is creates successfully . All the data is successfully getting stores in mongodb and cloudinary but the main issue is why the submit post button is not storing the data when clicked once but is doing its task when clicked twice or thrice . Following files are in main concern :-

CreatePost.js :-

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import M from "materialize-css";

const CreatePost = () => {
  const history = useHistory();
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
  const [body, setBody] = useState("");
  const [image, setImage] = useState("");
  const [url, seturl] = useState("");

  const postDetails = () => {
    const data = new FormData();
    data.append("file", image);
    data.append("upload_preset", "insta-clone");
    data.append("cloud_name", "manindercloud");
    fetch("https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/manindercloud/image/upload", {
      method: "post",
      body: data,
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        seturl(data.url);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });

    fetch("/createpost", {
      method: "post",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("jwt"),
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        title,
        body,
        pic: url,
      }),
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        if (data.error) {
          console.log(data.error);
          M.toast({ html: data.error, classes: "#b71c1c red darken-4" });
        } else {
          M.toast({
            html: "Created post successfully!",
            classes: "#66bb6a green lighten-1",
          });
          history.push("/");
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };

  return (
    <div
      className="card input-field"
      style={{
        margin: "30px auto",
        maxWidth: "500px",
        padding: "20px",
        textAlign: "center",
      }}
    >
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="title"
        value={title}
        onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)}
      />
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="body"
        value={body}
        onChange={(e) => setBody(e.target.value)}
      />
      <div className="file-field input-field">
        <div className="btn  #64b5f6 blue darker 1">
          <span>Upload Image</span>
          <input type="file" onChange={(e) => setImage(e.target.files[0])} />
        </div>
        <div className="file-path-wrapper">
          <input
            className="file-path validate"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Upload one or more images"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <button
        className="btn waves-effect waves-light #64b5f6 blue darker 1"
        onClick={() => {
          postDetails();
        }}
      >
        Submit Post
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CreatePost;
```

post.js:-

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const requireLogin = require("../middleware/requireLogin");
const User = mongoose.model("User");
const Post = mongoose.model("Post");

router.get("/allpost", (req, res) => {
  Post.find()
    .populate("postedBy", "_id name")
    .then((posts) => {
      res.json({ posts });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
});

router.post("/createpost", requireLogin, (req, res) => {
  const { title, body, pic } = req.body;
  if (!title || !body || !pic) {
    return res.status(422).json({ error: "please add all the fields!!" });
  }
  req.user.password = undefined;
  const post = new Post({
    title,
    body,
    photo: pic,
    postedBy: req.user,
  });
  post
    .save()
    .then((result) => {
      res.json({ post: result });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).json({});
    });
});

router.get("/mypost", requireLogin, (req, res) => {
  const { _id } = req.user;
  Post.find({ postedBy: _id })
    .populate("postedBy", "_id name")
    .then((mypost) => {
      res.json({ mypost });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).json({});
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: do you receive some message in the console?

Comment: @cityvoice ,  Again the same issue is happening even after executing the following answer , but now a warning is coming in the console . The warning is :-                                                                  
 Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.

Comment: I believe that one of the reasons for this strange behavior could be related to the fact that the second fetch within the `postDetails` function depends on the url obtained in the first fetch, it is possible that when executing this second fetch it still does not have access to url. One way to solve this is to chain the fetchs, or use async await that blocks until you have the data and move on, please see this example of this last option

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/v3p0unsc/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the code in the front end is continuing on to the fetch for the post request before it receives the response from the CDN, this will lead to that field not being filled out properly. So you'll need to make sure the fetch for the "/createpost" happens after receieving a response fro mthe CDN.

Answer (score 0):

Fetch is an async function, the param url used by your second fetch is updated by your first fetch, so you need to maintain their sequences. Additional, setUrl is an async function too, so you should change the code like this:

```
fetch("https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/manindercloud/image/upload", {..})
.then((res) => res.json())
.then((data) => {
   setUrl(data.url);
   fetch("/createpost", {
     ...
      body: JSON.stringify({
        title,
        body,
        pic: data.url,
      }),
   })
   .then(...)
 })
```